# Integration of manually locally installed libs into system?

Tags: installation, python, synaptic

I have manually built `numpy`, `scipy`, `matplotlib` etc - without root privilages. Now when I'm trying to install anything related - `synaptic` suggest me to install all the libs system wide. Is there a way I can tell `synaptic` to use the locally installed libs?

**Edit**:

All libs installed in the standard place:

```
~/.local/lib/python2.7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.

The Debian/Ubuntu package management (APT) has no control over your user-specific installed libraries. This is intentional. Intentional why? This would break security in a certain aspect - local users would have the ability to 'own' the system libraries.

In case you need specific versions of Python libraries I would recommend using [`pip`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to manage them in your local (home) directories. Also consider building your own `.deb` packages in case you want to distribute them in case other stuff doesn't break on this being installed system-wide.

Answer (score 1):

try copying the libs to the global directory. To do this type

```
sudo cp /path/to/lib /usr/lib
```

do this for every lib you want to copy.

Comment: I would recommend against using this. It will confuse your package management and possibly break stuff. Don't touch stuff in your `/usr/lib` directory, but use `/usr/local` if you really need to put it in a system-wide place.

Comment: Any way -- putting local things in system wide dir -- doesn't make synaptic aware of that stuff.

Comment: APT/Dpkg will not be aware of any file unless you've installed it using a package. No matter where you put it. Overwriting files in `/usr/lib` is generally harmful as it might break other stuff (no dependency checks for you!), whereas stuff in `/usr/local` *is meant for local changes to your system*.